# why Number([]) is 0 and Number(![]) is also 0?

Tags: javascript

I'm diving deep into JavaScript and came across some tricky behavior which I'm trying to understand. It's just learning purpose so please explain what's happening behind the scene if anyone knows.

Consider below outputs to understand what my concern is!

```
console.log(Number([])) // 0
console.log(Number([1])) // 1
```

The above output make sense as `[]` is blank it converts to 0 and if it has values then it converts to what value it holds in only first index.

```
console.log(Number(![])) // 0
console.log(Number(!0)) // 1 (not sure why)
console.log(Number([3,5])) // NaN (Not sure why)
```

The above three outputs are driving me crazy as I'm not getting what's happening there. Can anyone please explain what's happening under the hood?

Comment: Look for "coercion".

Comment: As @LazarLjubenović is saying, you might want to check out for example [this post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to type coercion, in this case both explicit and implicit.

```
Number([])
```

In the first example, the `Array#toString()` method is called on `[]`, which results in `""`. After that the empty String is explicitly coerced to a Number, and `Number("")` is 0.

```
Number([1])
```

In the second example the same is happening, just with `Number("1")` in the end.

```
Number(![])
```

In the example following that, you can see that normally, converting, and empty Array to a Boolean results in `true`, but since `!` is inverting the coercion to boolean, this results in `false`, which is then explicitly coerced to a Number, making it 0. Here, the `toString()` method is never used.

```
Number(!0)
```

The next example is very straightforward, `NOT 0`, or `!0` is simply `true`, which, when converted to a number is 1.

```
Number([3,5])
```

In the last example `NaN` get's printed out, because the result of `[3,5].toString()` is `3,5`, which isn't a Number.

Answer (score 4):

When passing a non primitive to the constructor, it is coerced into a primitive and then into a number:

```
 [3, 5] -> "3,5" -> NaN
 [] -> "" -> 0
 [1] -> "1" -> 1
```

When applying the negation operator (!) onto something that is converted into a boolean.

```
 !0 -> !false -> true -> 1
 !1 -> !true -> false -> 0
![] -> !true -> false -> 0
```

Comment: So in the case of ![] -> !"" ->  true -> 1? how it gives 0?

Comment: @pavan objects (arrays are objects) are truthy

Answer (score 0):

If you try console logging both values, you'll see that

- [] comes out as an empty array, which has a toString method that returns "", which is converted to zero by Number ()
- ![] comes out as false, which is also converted to zero

Comment: How ![] is 0. If [] turns out to 0 then !0 in boolean is true hence it should be 1. No?